# Xamarin cross platform database

Tags: database, sqlite, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, couchbase-lite

I'm developing a cross platform app  in Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android. I want to write a dal or repository layer once, and then make a reference to it from Android and iOS yo layers. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Forms take a look at this: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/

Comment: Sorry, no Forms... i use Xamarin.Android and Xamarín.iOS

Comment: even if you're not using Forms, the basic approach using SQLite outlined in that article will still apply

Comment: Bump for @Jason 's  comment.  The type of UI you use doesn't matter as you're dealing with data access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of thing is not possible for 1.x, as the API is not compatible with any PCL or .NET Standard profile (however, you can use shared projects to achieve something similar).  However, version 2.0 of the library is compiled as .NET Standard 1.4 and so you can create one assembly that can be referenced by any platform that also implements at least .NET Standard 1.4 (including Xamarin iOS and Android).

Comment: Sorry... But which 1.x library are you talking about?

Comment: You tagged the question with Couchbase Lite so I assumed you were using it.

Comment: Yeah...  My mistake. Thanks!